# how to get the datetime of the last transaction in a datomic db?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I want to find the most recent transaction made to a connection. The following does not seem to give the correct date:

```
(require '[datomic.api :as datomic])

(-> conn datomic/db datomic/basis-t datomic/t->tx (java.util.Date.))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
(defn last-transaction-time [db]
  (let [t (-> db datomic/basis-t)]
    [t (ffirst (datomic/q '[:find ?t
                            :in $ ?tx
                            :where [?tx :db/txInstant ?t]]
                          db
                          (datomic/t->tx t)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to `let` the result of your thread function up to the `datomic/t->tx`. Then use that to query for the transaction entity (implicitly created entity for each transaction). Each transaction entity has a `:db/txInstant` attribute that is implicitly added during a transaction. The value of that attribute is what you would want to pass to the `java.util.Date.` static method.

Answer (score 1):

Should be much easier

```
 (d/q
     '[:find (max 1 ?tx)
       :where
       [?tx :db/txInstant]]
     db)
```